# Converting XYZ tile request to govmap.gov.il requset which use EPSG:2039

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, c#, tiles

How to convert tile (x,y) as is the case with Google Maps, which is based on a regular Mercator.
To columns and rows for the govmap website that the coordinates are Israel Transverse Mercator (ITM)

How do I set the coordinates to this URL:
https://cdn.govmap.gov.il/020522B0B20R/L10/R00012d82/C0001013f.jpg

Based on this:
[https://cdn.govmap.gov.il/020522B0B20R/L{level}/R{row}/C{col}.png](https://cdn.govmap.gov.il/020522B0B20R/L%7Blevel%7D/R%7Brow%7D/C%7Bcol%7D.png) or jpg

I am using C# .net

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var url = "https://cdn.govmap.gov.il/M2023ORT3TS/{zoom_gov}/{y_gov}/{x_gov}.jpg";

int til_x = (Convert.ToInt32(x));
int til_y = (int)Math.Pow(2, z) - Convert.ToInt32(y) - 1;
url = url.Replace("{zoom_gov}", "L" + ZOOM_LAYER_ALI.Split(',')[0]);
url = url.Replace("{y_gov}", "R" + til_x.ToString("X8").ToLower());
url = url.Replace("{x_gov}", "C" + til_x.ToString("X8").ToLower());`
```